# Transferring data from one JSP to another JSP file using request

Tags: java, jsp, web

I am creating a bookstore application and was working on the checkout functionality. I ran into an issue where I am using this code to attempt to send data from shoppingCart.jsp to checkout.jsp.

```
ShoppingCart.jsp code:
request.setAttribute("bookData", bookList);
        request.setAttribute("insert","insert");
```

I am using this in checkout.jsp

```
        <%ArrayList<Book> bookstore = (ArrayList<Book>)request.getAttribute("bookData");
        String insert=(String)request.getAttribute("insert");

            %>
        <p> You Purchased the following books: </p>
        <h1><%=insert%></h1>
```

However, all I am receiving is Null value as such.
[image]

Is there an issue with what I am doing? I could not find what I am doing wrong even after searching online. Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: I want to pass data from a JSP to a JSP and not a servlet to a JSP.

Comment: The suggested solution in the comments was to use jsp:forward action. So I have a checkout <a href = "checkoutPage/checkout.jsp" class = "checkoutBtn">Checkout</a> as such. Where should I place my jsp:forward?

Comment: Instead of that, use HTTPSession to store the attributes and retrieve. HTTP Request is short lived.

Comment: so just changing req.setAttribute to session.setAttribute and similar for the get part should make it work? Do i still need the jsp:forward?

Comment: jsp:forward is to forward the same HTTP request object to another view. In your case, your HTTP request changes, so you do not need to forward the request. Session with attributes will help.

Comment: Thank you. Using sessions helped fixing it!